# About fixed point theorems

Tags: functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, contraction-operator

Lef $K$ be an operator defined on $L^{\infty}((0,1)\times(0,1))$ into itself.
$$K: L^{\infty}((0,1)\times(0,1)) \rightarrow L^{\infty}((0,1)\times(0,1)) $$
And maps the ball $B(0,M)$ into itself.

My question if I prove that the map $K$ is a contraction: for all $f_1,f_2 \in L^{\infty}((0,1)\times  (0,1))$ with $0<k<1$
$$||K(f_1)-K(f_2)||_{\infty} \leq k ||f_1-f_2||_{\infty}$$
Can I conclude that $K$ has a fixd point ?

Answer (score 0):

This is  map on a complete metric space, so any contraction on it has  fixed point by the Contraction Mapping Theorem.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping